# Rails testing with Selenium and everybody has a wrong password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium

I have an application with a bunch of cucumber tests, and I tried using selenium with it today. It took a bit, but I got it running, it starts up selenium, uses the correct database and everything, but everybody has a wrong password.

I can see the user getting created, I can log the password and see that it's the correct password, but every test user just gets redirected back to the login page with the incorrect username/password error.

Is this a Selenium problem, or some other dependent system or am I missing something? It works fine with the standard :rails webrat mode.

I run the task as

```
rake features
```

- Ubuntu 9.04
- machinist 0.3.1
- Selenium 1.1.14
- Firefox 3.0.10
- ruby 1.8.7-p160
- cucumber 0.3.7

EDIT: Now, after a restart (office reorg) it won't run tests at all. Firefox just starts, and shuts down, then everything fails.

```
14:13:25.141 ERROR - Failed to start new browser session, shutdown browser an clear all session data
org.openqa.selenium.server.RemoteCommandException: timed out waiting for window 'null' to appear
```

I've tried updating the selenium-server.jar from the latest version, and no dice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Cucumber::Rails.use_transactional_fixtures
```

Was the culprit. In selenium you can't have transactional fixtures, so writing cucumber steps will be a bit more fun, but whatever. Commenting out the above line fixes the password problem.